# MySQL keeping returning a row even though nothing is in database that matches query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

$query_check_homework keeps failing even though there is nothing in the database.  I am sure this is probably something really simple like a syntax error but I have been working at this for over an hour and cannot get it working. Could you please take a look at the code and let me know why it keeps returning a row even though nothing is in the database that matches the query.

Here is the code.

```
/*Check if homework name already exists*/
$query_check_homework = $this->db_connection->query("
SELECT 
    homework.homework_name
FROM classes 
    INNER JOIN homework On classes.class_id = homework.class_id
WHERE 
    homework.class_id = '".$this->class_id."' And
homework.homework_name = '".$this->homework_name."' And
classes.user_id = '".$this->user_id."'");       

if ($query_check_homework == 1) {
    $this->errors[] = "Sorry, You already have homework in this class with that name. Please choose a different name.";
} 
else {
    /*write new homework into the datebase*/
    $query_new_homework = $this->db_connection->query("
    INSERT INTO homework (class_id, homework_name, avaliable_points, earned_points,     date) VALUES ('".$this->class_id."', '".$this->homework_name."', '".$this-  >avaliable_points."', '".$this->earned_points."', '".$this->homework_date."')");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are, depending on what DB connection class you're using, that $query_check_homework only contains a pointer to a result set, and will always "==1", or "true", simply by virtue of not being false, or 0.

Instead, consider using a function which counts the number of results returned from a query:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add the num_rows function on the end. It should have looked like `$query_check_user_name->num_rows == 1`